# Escape sequences in strings using ASCII values in decimal?

Tags: python, escaping, byte, ascii

Escape sequences in Python support both hex (like `'\xab'`) and octal (like `\12`) values. Is there a way to specify the ASCII code as a decimal value (probably like `\n99`)? I searched a little bit but was surprised to find nothing.

Comment: given the [section in the official documentation on escape codes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), I'd say no.

Comment: Doesn't use escape code, but `chr` might be useful.

Comment: If you're searching for something that doesn't exist, it's not surprising that you didn't find anything.

Comment: @Barmar just wondering whether there are some other shortcuts for this if missing the nature extension to decimal is by design.

Comment: @Thomson I can't think of any language that provides decimal escape sequences. Many only have octal, some also have hex.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for doesn't exist in Python.

Numeric escape codes are typically in hex (or less frequently, octal), because that's the obvious choice for their intended uses.
From the table in *The Python Language Reference*, [2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Notes:
>   
>   [...]
>   
>   3. In a bytes literal, hexadecimal and octal escapes denote the **byte** with the given value. In a string literal, these escapes denote a **Unicode character** with the given value.

(Emphasis added.
Thanks to Evert for providing the link in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883401#comment72869414_42883401).)

To represent a **byte**, you must specify exactly 8 bits.
At 4 bits per hex digit, this requires *exactly* two hex digits.
Converting 8 bits to 2 hex digits and back is much easier than converting those same 8 bits to and from two-point-something decimal digits --- there's no need to multiply (or divide) by 16 in your head.

To represent a **Unicode character**, you must specify a code point in the Unicode *code space*, which is [defined](http://unicode.org/glossary/#codespace) as "a range of integers from 0 to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub>".
Since these are officially represented in hexadecimal (`U+0020`, `U+FFFE`, etc.), hex escape codes are the only reasonable choice --- they require literally no effort at all.